# Is it possible to automatically print document the entire PDF file when a file is auto saved to Google Drive Folder by Language Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've developed a program that exports PDF files to a Google Drive folder automatically.
 I intend to print the entire set of exported PDF files wirelessly using my printer with the help of the Google App Script language.
Unfortunately, when I attempted to run the script, I encountered an error message that the PdfApp library was undefined.
After researching the issue, I discovered that I needed to add the PdfApp library to my script. However, when I searched for the PdfApp library's search ID, I couldn't find it.

Is there any other way to resolve this problem? I've written a script to print all of the PDF files in my Google folder, which I've included below.

Since I've already created the PDF export code, I'll only provide the print document code. Can you please assist me in correcting the code?
**Folder ID**:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mrAHm29XWv-0WPFN6WLludnBNcjA1ifv
**Google Sheet link**:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q9y1XyoL1aJgiIADCoU7tu40wp-_fVnw9hKdY3yA0fU/edit#gid=0
**Printer Name**:SHARP MX-2517FN SPDL2-c

Thank you so much

```js
function printPDFs() {
  var folderId = "1mrAHm29XWv-0WPFN6WLludnBNcjA1ifv";
  var printerName = "SHARP MX-2517FN SPDL2-c";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = getAllPDFFilesInFolder(folder);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var blob = file.getBlob();
    var pdfDoc = PdfApp.open(blob);
    var pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
      var page = pages[i];
      var imageData = page.getAs("image/jpeg");
      var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create("tempDoc");
      var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.insertImage(imageData, 1, 1);
      var url = doc.getUrl();
      var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.indexOf("?"));
      var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      pdfFile.makeCopy(file.getName() + "_page_" + (i + 1));
      doc.setTrashed(true);
      var newFile = folder.getFilesByName(file.getName() + "_page_" + (i + 1)).next();
      var newBlob = newFile.getBlob();
      newBlob.setName(newFile.getName());
      newBlob.setContentType("application/pdf");
      var printer = getPrinterByName(printerName);
      printer.print(newBlob);
    }
  }
}

function getPrinterByName(name) {
  var printers = CloudPrint.getPrinters();
  for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; i++) {
    if (printers[i].name === name) {
      return printers[i];
    }
  }
  throw new Error("Printer not found: " + name);
}

function getAllPDFFilesInFolder(folder) {
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  var childFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFiles = getAllPDFFilesInFolder(childFolders.next());
    files = concatenateFileIterators(files, childFiles);
  }
  return files;
}

function concatenateFileIterators(iterator1, iterator2) {
  var arr = [];
  while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
    arr.push(iterator1.next());
  }
  while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
    arr.push(iterator2.next());
  }
  return arr[Symbol.iterator]();
}
```

Comment: Google Cloud Print is deprecated.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal  is there any other way?